# pass a multidimensional array element id as an option in a jquery function

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

I'm new at jQuery and normally I would search this myself untill I find it but I'm running out of time... So I hope someone can help me.

```
<select name="txtshort" id="txtshort">
    <option value="Achyranthes+AC0-and+AC0-Plantago+AC0-Formula">Ach+AC0-pl</option>
    <option value="Aconite+AC0-and+AC0-G.L.+AC0-Combination">Ac+AC0-gl</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtformula" name="txtformula" value="">
<input type="text" id="txtdose" name="txtdose" value="">
<input type="text" id="txtform" name="txtform" value="">

<script type="text/javascript" >
var array A=[
    {
        "mednr":"5",
        "short":"Ach+AC0-pl",
        "formula":"Achyranthes+AC0-and+AC0-Plantago+AC0-Formula",
        "dose":"250",
        "quant":"2/d",
        "form":"Tabletten"
    },{
        "mednr":"6",
        "short":"Ac+AC0-gl",
        "formula":"Aconite+AC0-and+AC0-G.L.+AC0-Combination",
        "dose":"2/d",
        "form":"Tabletten"
    }
]; 

jQuery(document).on("change", "#txtshort", function() { 
  jQuery("#txtformula").val(opzoekenMedicijn(jQuery("#txtshort").val(),"vorm"));
}).val( jQuery('#txtformula').val() ).change();

 var searchMed = function(afk, key){
 for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (A[i].formule == afk){
        return A[i].key;   
    }
 }
};
</script>
```

So when the value of my select box changes i want to change the value in the txt boxes to their corresponding value in the array. I use the formula as a search key and I want the value from  A[i].dose in txtdose and the value of A[i].form in txtform... 
I've written a function to search the right value but the part where I sent the key in my function gives the error: undefined and I van only change 1 html txtboxes in the "onchange" event.

correct way to do this:

thanks to Dave!!

```
<select name="txtshort" id="txtshort">
<option value="Achyranthes+AC0-and+AC0-Plantago+AC0-Formula">Ach+AC0-pl</option>
<option value="Aconite+AC0-and+AC0-G.L.+AC0-Combination">Ac+AC0-gl</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtformula" name="txtformula" value="">
<input type="text" id="txtdose" name="txtdose" value="">
<input type="text" id="txtform" name="txtform" value="">

<script type="text/javascript" >
var array A=[
{
    "mednr":"5",
    "short":"Ach+AC0-pl",
    "formula":"Achyranthes+AC0-and+AC0-Plantago+AC0-Formula",
    "dose":"250",
    "quant":"2/d",
    "form":"Tabletten"
},{
    "mednr":"6",
    "short":"Ac+AC0-gl",
    "formula":"Aconite+AC0-and+AC0-G.L.+AC0-Combination",
    "dose":"2/d",
    "form":"Tabletten"
}
]; 
var searchMed = function(search){
  for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (A[i].formule == search){
      return A[i];   
    }
  }
};

jQuery(document).on("change", "#txtshort", function() { 
  var base = opzoekenMedicijn( jQuery("#afkorting").val() ); 
  jQuery("#txtformula").val(base.formula);  
  jQuery("#txtdose").val(base.dose);
  jQuery("#txtform").val(base.form);
});


</script>
```

Comment: don't forget to include something like `if(!base)return` before getting all the various `base.whatever` bits. Otherwise it will be writing a lot of log warnings whenever the value wasn't found in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a while to figure out what you're doing, but the issue is how you're trying to get a named attribute.

```
var myObject = {foo:"hi", bar:"bye"};
var lookFor = "foo";
console.log( myObject.lookFor ); // undefined: myObject has no attribute "lookFor"
console.log( myObject[lookFor] ); // "hi": lookFor = "foo", myObject.foo is "hi"
```

So change `.key` to `[key]` and it will work.

A more typical way to do this would be to just return the object:

```
function opzoekenMedicijn( search ) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayFromPHP.length; i++) {
        if (arrayFromPHP[i].formule == search){
            return arrayFromPHP[i]; 
        }
    }
};
```

then use it like this:

```
var value = opzoekenMedicijn( "lookForThis" ).formule;
```

although you'll need to be careful not to search for keys which don't exist, or handle the return specially:

```
var found = opzoekenMedicijn( "lookForThis" );
var value = found && found.formule;
```

(also I suggest breaking your code up a bit to use variables; everything on one line is hard to follow. Use an optimising minifier to create a compacted release version)

Comment: Perfect! I will put the complete answer here because now it is very confusing :)